# JButtons don't follow the intended handlers?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, procedure

I'm making a minesweeper game, in the first part, I'm deciding whether or not there is a bomb at a certain button by using `boolean1` (the field is a 16x16 array) I have tested this part, and the output is correct. 50 random `true` values and the rest are `false` my problem starts at the second part, where I want to get a certain action by the button based on the value of the `boolean1`. When implementing the code, all of the `jbuttons`follow the second `ActionListener` where the icon is set to `bomb` I want to get the `jbuttons` to also follow the first handler.

1st procedure

```
static void placeMines() 
        {
                for (int x=0;x<16;x++)
                {
                    for (int y=0;y<16;y++)
                    {
                        if(boolean1[x][y]=(true))
                        {
                            boolean1[x][y]=false;
                        }
                    }
                }



                int minesPlaced = 0;
                Random random = new Random(); 
                while(minesPlaced < 50) 
                {
                  int a = random.nextInt(Width);
                  int b = random.nextInt(Height);
                  boolean1[a][b]=(true);
                  minesPlaced ++;
                }
        }
```

2nd procedure:

```
static void buttonfunctions()
{       
        for(int c=0;c<16;c++)
        {
            for(int d=0;d<16;d++)
            {
                if (boolean1[c][d]=false)
                {   
                    final int temp3=c;
                    final int temp4=d;

                    jbuttons[c][d].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                            {

                                        jbuttons[temp3][temp4].setIcon(clickedCell);

                            }
                    });
                }
                if(boolean1[c][d]=true)
                {
                    final int temp1=c;
                    final int temp2=d;

                    jbuttons[temp1][temp2].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                                {                           
                                            jbuttons[temp1][temp2].setIcon(bomb);                   
                                }
                        });
                }

            }   
        }

}
```

Comment: `JButton` has a nice little method `putClientProperty` and `getClientProperty` which allows you to associate more data with the button, this might be a way to overcome needing yet another array.  I might   store the cell (x/y) of button and when required simply lookup the model to determine the state of the model ... as an idea

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check if a boolean is true, you want to do :

```
if (myBoolean)
```

doing

```
if (myBoolean == true)
```

is equivalent, but more verbose than needed.

doing

if (myBoolean = true) is syntactically correct, but has the effect of assigning true to myBoolean, and then evaluating the result of the assignment, which is `true`. So, going back to your code:

If the intent of the following code is to reset the matrix:

```
   if(boolean1[x][y]=(true))
   {
      boolean1[x][y]=false;
   }
```

then you should just do

```
boolean1[x][y] = false;
```

Also

```
if (boolean1[c][d]=false)
```

should probably be:

```
if (! boolean1[c][d])
```

There may be more stuff wrong with your code, but you may want to start fixing this.

Comment: what is this? this doesnt answer any of the questions of the user - its just lecturing